# How do I specify the "model_config_file" variable to tensorflow-serving in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, tensorflow, docker-compose, tensorflow-serving

I will preface this by saying that I am inexperienced with docker and docker-compose. I am trying to convert my `docker run ...` command to a *docker-compose.yml* file, however, I cannot get the *models.config* file to be found.

I am able to correctly run a tensorflow-serving docker container using the following `docker run ...` command:

```
docker run -t --rm \
  tensorflow/serving \
  -p 8501:8501 \
  -v "$(pwd)/models/:/models/" \
  --model_config_file=/models/models.config \
  --model_config_file_poll_wait_seconds=60
```

This works as expected, and the *models.config* file is found in the container at `/models/models.config` as expected.

The tensorflow-serving pages do not mention anything about docker-compose, however, I would much rather use this than a `docker run ...` command. My attempt at a docker-compose file is:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  server:
    image: tensorflow/serving
    ports:
      - '8501:8501'
    volumes:
      - './models:/models'
    environment:
      - 'model_config_file=/models/models.config'
      - 'model_config_file_poll_wait_seconds=60'
```

Using this docker-compose file, the container runs, however, it seems like the environment variables are completely ignored, so I'm not sure if this is how I should set them. The container image looks in the default location for the *models.config* file, and it doesn't exist there, and so it does not load the configuration defined in *models.config*.

**So, how can I define these values, or run a tensorflow-serving container, using docker-compose?**

I appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Try without the quotes or like that : `environment:
                        model_config_file: /models/models.config`

Comment: @BatchenRegev I have found a solution - see my posted answer; add those options under a `command` section.

Answer (score 9):

So I have come across a solution elsewhere that I haven't found on any threads/posts/etc that talk about tensorflow/serving, so I will post my answer here.

Adding those options underneath a `command` section, as follows, works.

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  server:
    image: tensorflow/serving
    ports:
      - '8501:8501'
    volumes:
      - './models:/models'
    command:
      - '--model_config_file=/models/models.config'
      - '--model_config_file_poll_wait_seconds=60'
```

I don't know a lot about docker so I don't know if this is an obvious answer, but I didn't find a solution even after a lot of Google'ing.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the option `--model_config_file` is not an environment variable. It is an argument that you can pass to the command that is set as an entrypoint in the image `tensorflow/serving`. 
If we look at the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/tools/docker/Dockerfile#L59) that was used to build the image, we can see :

```
# Create a script that runs the model server so we can use environment variables
# while also passing in arguments from the docker command line
RUN echo '#!/bin/bash \n\n\
tensorflow_model_server --port=8500 --rest_api_port=8501 \
--model_name=${MODEL_NAME} --model_base_path=${MODEL_BASE_PATH}/${MODEL_NAME} \
"$@"' > /usr/bin/tf_serving_entrypoint.sh \
&& chmod +x /usr/bin/tf_serving_entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/tf_serving_entrypoint.sh"]
```

This script accept various arguments (you can see them by running `docker run -t --rm tensorflow/serving --help`)

As far as I know, the only environment variables used by TF serving are `MODEL_VERSION` and `MODEL_NAME`. `model_config_file` and `model_config_file_poll_wait_seconds` are just arguments to the CLI serving executable.

To achieve the result you are after, you could override the entrypoint of the docker image by setting your own entrypoint in the `docker-compose.yml` :

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  server:
    image: tensorflow/serving
    ports:
      - '8501:8501'
    volumes:
      - './models:/models'
    entrypoint:
      - /usr/bin/tf_serving_entrypoint.sh
      - --model_config_file=/models/models.config
      - --model_config_file_poll_wait_seconds=60
```

(**Note** : I did not test that `docker-compose.yml` file)